# Django — async_to_sync vs asyncio.run

Tags: python, django, python-asyncio, django-channels

We can use both functions to run any async function synchronously:

```
import asyncio
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync

asyncio.run(asyncio.sleep(1))
async_to_sync(asyncio.sleep)(1)
```

What is the difference? Can we *always* use `asyncio.run` instead of `async_to_sync`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Differences

1. They have different purposes. `async_to_sync` turns an awaitable into a synchronous callable, and `asyncio.run` executes a coroutine and return the result.
2. According to [documentation](https://github.com/django/asgiref/blob/4fa1c540c33552dbf109a6fa65475561bab2adc8/asgiref/sync.py#L18), a callable from `async_to_sync` works in a **subthread**.
3. `async_to_sync` does not create an event loop per-thread in case when you're inside synchronous code which is produced by `sync_to_async` and running inside asynchronous code. It reuses a loop of asynchronous code. Let's take an example:

```py
import asyncio
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync, sync_to_async

async def running(n):
    return [await sync_to_async(sync)(i) for i in range(n)]

def sync(n):
    # it will create a new loop for every call
    return asyncio.run(from_sync(n))

async def from_sync(n):
    return n

print("Result:", asyncio.run(running(3)))
```

This one will run 4 loops: 1 to call `running` and 3 to call `from_sync`.

If we use `async_to_sync` instead of `asyncio.run` inside `sync` we will reduce the number of loops to 1 to call `running`.

To see it you can wrap `new_event_loop` function:

```py
def print_deco(fn, msg):
    def inner():
        res = fn()
        print(msg, res)
        return res
    return inner
p = asyncio.get_event_loop_policy()
p.new_event_loop = print_deco(p.new_event_loop, "NEW EVENT LOOP:")
```

You can find a detailed explanation in this [post](https://www.aeracode.org/2017/10/18/channels-2-october/).

Comment: What will happen if I run async code using `asyncio.run` instead of `async_to_sync`?

Comment: @MaxMalyshIReinstateMonica As stated in [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/async/), you are likely to get a [SynchronousOnlyOperation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/exceptions/#django.core.exceptions.SynchronousOnlyOperation) error (since django 3.0) which can be disabled by with `os.environ["DJANGO_ALLOW_ASYNC_UNSAFE"] = "true"`, but there is also a warning: "If you enable this option and there is parallel access to asynchronous unsafe parts of Django, you may suffer data loss or corruption".

Comment: This will happen only if we make a _synchronous_ call inside an asynchronous function (e.g. if we will call django ORM inside an event loop). This is why we need to wrap synchronous calls into sync_to_async. My question was about async ---> sync, not the vice versa.

Comment: @MaxMalyshIReinstateMonica You are right. I have updated the answer